# Included HTML component ignores width

Tags: html, css, angular, tailwind-css, daisyui

I cannot seem to find a problem or I am misunderstanding something (I use daisyui + nx + tailwind css + angular). Very simplified scenarios for my problem:

1. For first scenario I have:

```
<div class="flex flex-row">
  <div class="btn btn-primary w-1/2"></div>
  <app-home-side-bar></app-home-side-bar>
</div>
```

where side-bar component is:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary w-1/2"></div>
```

the result:
[image]

However,

2. In this scenario I have everything in one place:

```
<div class="flex flex-row">
  <div class="btn btn-primary w-1/2"></div>
  <div class="btn btn-primary w-1/2"></div>
</div>
```

the result:
[image]

Why included component ignores the 50% width parameter?

Answer (score 1):

you can make rendering behave like app-home-side-bar component tag doesn't exist.

app-home-side-bar.scss

```
:host {
  display: contents;
}
```

the result is the same as side-bar internal nodes were direct children of the tag where it was rendered

Comment: Hi, is this supposed to be a proper solution and not a workaround? Will I need to be including this snippet in all .scss child files? Seems a bit bizarre.

Comment: well it depends.... sometimes it makes sense to use exactly this trick. I just proposed a solution that works. In general I would say parent components should control where cheir chilren are placed, and children components should just try to ocupy whole width given to them in majority of cases

Answer (score 1):

#### Using the attribute selector to initialize the component, so that no CSS changes will be needed!

In the below example, we have changed the `selector` property to check the attribute `ComponentSelector` instead of the html tags, this has the advantage that the component CSS is not messed up, since we initialize through the attributes!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[ComponentSelector]',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div></div>
  `,
  host: {
    class: 'btn btn-primary w-1/2',
  },
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Usage on the parent

```
<div class="flex flex-row">
  <div class="btn btn-primary w-1/2"></div> 
  <div class="btn btn-primary w-1/2" ComponentSelector></div><!-- note this addition, I am initializing the component using attributes instead of element selector -->
</div>
```

---

#### Alternative

Please add the CSS to the angular tag that contains the HTML, you need to add it to the `host` property of `@component` decorator, this will ensure the CSS gets applied to the root component selector.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div></div>
  `,
  host: {
    class: 'btn btn-primary w-1/2',
  },
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: Hi, would you consider this a good practice? Okay, I could write `<app-home-side-bar class="grow"></app-home-side-bar>` or as you mentioned (modified) `host: { class: 'grow' }` and it works, but I'd like to keep everything clean and understandable - can I do this within my actual HTML component (template), instead of modifying `@component` decorator? It would seem more easier to manage.

Comment: @CaptainJacky In angular we have this small limitation, that we need to style the component selector sometimes to make the CSS work, its a minor thing and its ok to do, that is why angular offers these options to overcome this hiccup, like using `:host` to style the component selector or `host` to add a class, its ok is what I mean. If you do not want to use CSS to fix it, let me suggest an alternative solution, but there is  no best practices here, just do the thing that solves your issue! The component is the fundamental unit to reuse code blocks, styling it is upto the end user only!